# How do I remove this "index" text from a Pandas DataFrame HTML Table?

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table, mode

I think I'm missing something I cannot seem to figure out how to remove this index text from the top left of my HTML pivotTable or maybe my data is formatted incorrectly. I am using Mode but it's constructing this HTML pivot table with Pandas using DataFrame. I've tried everything like .hide_index()
rename_index and so on

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9vcn9.jpg

```
df = datasets[9]
df.rename(columns={'program': 'Program', 'agent': 'Agent', 'dials': 'Dials','conversations': 'Conversations', 'successes': 'Successes'},  inplace=True)

table = pd.pivot_table(df, values=['Dials', 'Successes'], index=['Agent'], columns=['Program'], aggfunc=np.sum, margins=True, margins_name='Total', fill_value=0)
table = table.applymap(lambda x: '' if x == 0 else '{:,}'.format(x))

mode.export_csv(table, index=False)

def hover(hover_color="#ffff00"):
  return dict(selector="tr:hover",
  props=[("background-color", "%s" % hover_color)])
  
table_styles = [
    hover(),

   
    dict(selector="caption", props=[("caption-side", "bottom")]),
    dict(selector="")
]

table = (table.style.set_table_styles(table_styles)
            .set_caption(""))  

table
```

Comment: if you want to remove only text `index` then it may not have function for this.

Comment: instead of `"%s" % hover_color` you can use directly `hover_color`. And if you expect valeus which are not strings then simpler is `str(hover_color)`